# Find script what sets button on focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, drupal

On a Drupal page a button element gets focused before the page has been loaded completely.

I'm trying to locate where this happens but unfortunately I wasn't able to track down the script. I'm using Chrome and tried to set a break-point but no luck. Further I tried to locate the line where this happens with the profiler. Also no luck so far. Do anyone know how to debug this properly? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

When I replace  with a div, the issue is gone, so its related to the button element itself (no class nor element id)

Comment: It would be next to impossible to debug this without seeing any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is right-click on the element you think is going to trigger the event and on the context menu click inspect.  The chrome developer bar will open and you should see the html tag for that element you clicked on.  On this bar there are two section: one with html tags and the others with tabs named Style, Computed, Event Listeners, DOM Breakpoints and Properties.

The one you want is Event Listeners, so click on that tab. Now we see all the listener for that html element grouped event type.  When open a group you should see the list of element on left with a link to that specific line of code for the event handler.  If you click on the link, you will be switch to the file where the code is.

Now the hard part.  As you will see in some web pages, there are a lot of handlers.  Also the use of libraries like JQuery make it harder to find the piece of code that really does something and the code is probably minified.

So let's supposed you found the code that you want to debug.  Often it's in a format like

```
var namespace = {
    ...
  handler: function(event) {
    /* Event handler code here */
  },
    ...
```

In a case like that, this might work

```
(function () {
  var old_handler = namespace.handler;
  namespace.handler = function () {
    debugger; // this make a breakpoint here and stops
    old_handler.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})();
```

When all fails, make a local copy of the file that contains the code and setup an Apache server so that you proxy the web site except for that file which you will reference locally.  Then you can modify it however you like. This won't work on https web site.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found it :)